# How to open the current directory on Bash on Windows?

Tags: windows, bash, microsoft-file-explorer

I know that in MacOS, people use the `open .` command to open the current directory in a file manager.

Does anybody know the appropriate command to do the same task in Bash on Windows?

Answer (score 91):

On Windows with Git Bash, just type:

```
start .
```

it will open the current directory in the file explorer.

Comment: `/mnt/c/Windows/System32/start: line 1: $'AcrSch2Svc\r': command not found` What do I do in that case ?

Comment: Worked for me on Windows w/ Git Bash.

Answer (score 34):

You can now call explorer.exe from the bash subsystem. I've set up an alias to use it. I've added the copy to clipboard alias as well for good measure.

**Alias:**

```
alias open="explorer.exe"
alias pbcopy="clip.exe"
```

**Example:**

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | pbcopy
open .
open "D:\\Dir"
```

The open alias plays well with `.`, but you'll need to pass it the Windows path if you want to specify a directory.

Comment: Regarding the windows path restriction, you can use the command `cygpath --windows <path>` to convert. [Read more here.](https://cygwin.com/faq.html#faq.using.converting-paths)

Comment: ```wslpath``` is the subsystem version

Answer (score 8):

Right now Microsoft don't recommend to mix Windows explorer with the bash shell. In latest win10 Insider builds you could use from bash something like this

```
cmd.exe /c start .
```

If you are using Win10 Anniversary Edition you could try installing a Desktop Environment. Start reading this
https://github.com/microsoft/bashonwindows/issues/637
After that you could open a window with the present folder content with

```
gnome-open .
```

Comment: it seems that cmd.exe (or any other windows .exe file) cannot be executed from WSL bash, did you actually test this, or are you guessing?  When I enter "cmd.exe /c start ." I get "Exec format error".

Comment: I just tested on latest insider build 14971 and it works but it always opens C:\Windows\System32 folder.

Answer (score 7):

**You Can Use the following command:** `explorer .`

Answer (score 6):

I'm using this function:

```
open()
{
    explorer.exe  `wslpath -w "$1"`
}
```

So if you are in `/mnt/c/Users/` and would like to open that folder, just type `open .`

`wslpath` [will resolve only paths from the Windows system](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/3146#issuecomment-386810991), be aware. If you are looking to do something like `open ~` it will not work, and you will get:

`wslpath: /home/my-user: Result not representable`

Command usage

```
wslpath usage:
  -a    force result to absolute path format
  -u    translate from a Windows path to a WSL path (default)
  -w    translate from a WSL path to a Windows path
  -m    translate from a WSL path to a Windows path, with ‘/’ instead of ‘\\’

  EX: wslpath ‘c:\users’
```

A proof that this works:

[image: wsdlpath working]

Comment: Not answering the question sorry

Comment: For Ubuntu Bash on Windows I get `wslpath: .: Invalid argument` .

Comment: You have to setup the alias first @dotnetCarpenter

Comment: I'm up voting this since it works but the explanation is terrible. First `open` is not an alias but a function. Your can put in your `.profile`, `.bashrc`, `bash_aliases` etc. whatever is `source` when you open your terminal. Second, `wslpath` now translate paths from within `lxfs` and `tmpfs`  to Windows path correctly. E.i. paths within your Linux subsystem.

Comment: @dotnetCarpenter feel free to modify my answer if it's so "terrible"

Comment: Works great for me on Ubuntu Bash (WSL), this is the best answer.

Answer (score 3):

I have added

```
alias open='explorer.exe  `wslpath -w "$1"`'
```

to the `.bashrc` file

opens current folder when typed `open`

I'm using windows ubuntu subsystem.

Answer (score 2):

start . - this is the equivalent of open . in bash

Answer (score 2):

This command should do it:

```
$ explorer
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
$ explorer .
```

This will work on bash command in windows. I was using R studio and was able to open the directory.

Answer (score 1):

If `start .` doesn't work for you, it's essentially the same as running `explorer.exe .` so you can create an alias for it which is what I did.

```
alias start="explorer.exe"
```

Side note: Another useful one to have is `BROWSER`. explorer.exe is capable of starting your default web browser. This comes in handy when you run scripts that open a web browser like starting a React.js development server.

```
export BROWSER="explorer.exe"
```

Answer (score 0):

To work in all type of paths (Windows-Style and Linux-Style), do as following ([the answer of mine to my own question on SU](https://superuser.com/a/1315937/370509)):

(Here my challenge was how I could open Explorer in current working directory with Linux-Style path for view purposes, if you are going into modification or do something else other than just viewing, this is at your own risk, please also read [**Do not change Linux files using Windows apps and tools**](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2016/11/17/do-not-change-linux-files-using-windows-apps-and-tools/)):

```
explorer.exe "C:\Users\userNmae\AppData\Local\Lxss$(sed 's:/:\\:g' <<<"$PWD")"
```

this will open the Explorer exactly in your working directory. The only thing you need is now define a function to get it to work. You can add this into your `.bashrc` and source it or re-open Bash.

```
xplor(){ 
    explorer.exe "C:\Users\userName\AppData\Local\Lxss$(sed 's:/:\\:g' <<<"$PWD")";
 }
```

**Note**: Replace `userName` with your Windows User account name there.

Answer (score 0):

In WSL2 it looks like the `open` command is now doing what `start` does in Windows command. I just put an alias in my .bashrc

```
start="open"
```

Now you can do either `start .` or `open .` depending on your preferences.

Answer (score 0):

Using the MINGW64 shell that comes with Git for Windows, I created these functions in my .profile:

```sh
function towinpath {
    { cd "$1" && pwd -W; } | sed 's|/|\\|g'
}

function open {
    path_to_open=""

    if [ -f "$1" ]; then
        filename=$(basename "$1")
        win_dirname=$(towinpath "$(dirname "$1")")
        path_to_open="$win_dirname\\$filename"
    elif [ -d "$1" ]; then
        path_to_open=$(towinpath "$1")
    else
        # Take our chances with windows explorer ...
        path_to_open="$1"
    fi

    if [ -z "$path_to_open" ]; then
        echo "Failed to open $1"
    else
        explorer "$path_to_open"
    fi
}
```

This seems to work with just about everything you can throw at Windows File Explorer:

```sh
open .                         # Opens the current directory
open ../                       # Opens the directory above this one
open /c/Windows                # Opens C:\Windows
open ~/AppData                 # Opens my AppData folder
open ~/*.csv                   # Opens the first CSV file in my home directory in Excel
open https://stackoverflow.com # Opens StackOverflow in my browser!

# Opens paths with spaces in them too:
open /c/Program\ Files/Sublime\ Text\ 3/sublime_text.exe
open '/c/Program Files/Sublime Text 3/sublime_text.exe'
```

Answer (score 0):

To open the current directory via windows subsystem for linux (WSL) use :

```
 $ explorer.exe .
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to edit `.bash_aliases`

```sh
nano ~/.bash_aliases
# add
alias open='explorer.exe $1'
# save and close: cltr-s, cltr-x
source ~/.bash_aliases
```

Now, we can use: `open .` or `open documents`

Answer (score 0):

Opening Windows Terminal in a directory and typing **start bash** will open a bash terminal in that directory.